# I roll a fair die 4 times. Let X be the number of different outcomes that I see. Find $\mathbb{E}[X]$

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value

I roll a fair die 4 times. Let X be the number of different outcomes that I see. Find $\mathbb{E}[X]$.

My attempt:

I know that I can write X as a sum of indicator random variables and then I can use the fact that $\mathbb{E}[1_A]=\mathbb{P}(A)$. Thus,

\begin{equation}
I_{A_1}=
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if only one kind}\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
I_{A_2}=
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if two kinds}\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
I_{A_3}=
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if three kinds}\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
I_{A_4}=
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{all different}\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

Then the probabilities of event A happening for each is
$$\mathbb{P}(I_{A_1})=\frac{6\cdot1\cdot1\cdot1}{6^4}$$
$$\mathbb{P}(I_{A_2})=\frac{6\cdot5\cdot2\cdot2}{6^4}$$
$$\mathbb{P}(I_{A_3})=\frac{6\cdot5\cdot4\cdot3}{6^4}$$
$$\mathbb{P}(I_{A_4})=\frac{6\cdot5\cdot4\cdot3}{6^4}$$

The sum of these should be my desired expectation.

My question is whether or not I have found the probabilities correctly. This is my thought process for how I counted the number of choices for the numerator, using $I_{A_2}$ as an example:

There are 6 choices for choosing the first number, then we don't want to get that number again so then there are 5 choices. After that, we only want to get the first or second number again, thus there are 2 choices for the third roll and 2 choices for the fourth roll. Hence, $6\cdot5\cdot2\cdot2$.

Is this the correct way of thinking about it? Thanks

Comment: I commented earlier, but I had misunderstood the question...oops. [Here](https://www.online-python.com/1T8Z9YoQEC) is a quick Python program that runs 100000 trials of this problem. It looks like something doesn't line up, as I get an expected value of about 3.1 here. I'll see if I can figure something out.

Comment: The issue is that in counting the possibilities, you assume (in the case of 2 possibilities) that already the second throw is different from the first one. But you could also have the first two equal to each other and the second two equal to each other but different from the first two. Try to think about that.

Comment: In case there is any confusion:  I posted an answer and then deleted it.  My answer was based on the algorithm $\sum_{k=1}^4 kp(k)$, where $p(k) =$ the probability of having exactly $k$ distinct numbers occur out of the 4 rolls.  You are choosing an alternative algorithm, that is also valid, but tricky.  Therefore, since I don't have that much experience with the algorithm that you chose, I'm going to leave this query alone.

Answer (score 7):

Let $(X_i)$ be an indicator r.v. that equals $1$ if face $i$ appears in $4$ rolls, and $0$ otherwise

Let $X$ be the number of distinct faces that have appeared, then

$ X = X_1 + X_2 + ... +X_6$

and $\Bbb E(X) = \Bbb E(X_1) + \Bbb E(X_2) + ... + \Bbb E(X_6) =6\Bbb E(X_i)$ by symmetry

Now the expectation of an indicator variable is just the probability of the event it indicates, so

$\Bbb E(X_i) = \Bbb P(X_i) = 1 - \left(\frac 5 6\right)^4$

and $\Bbb E(X) = 6\Bbb E(X_i) = 6\left(1- \left(\frac 5 6\right)^4\right) = \dfrac{671}{216}, \approx 3.1065$

Answer (score 3):

This is a very brute-force-y problem, or at least I have a very brute-force-y solution. If anyone has a more elegant solution, please post it.

I want to start by saying that the sum of your probabilities should equal 1, as they comprise all the possible outcomes, yet they don't. $\mathbb P\left(A_1\right)$ and $\mathbb P\left(A_4\right)$ are correct, but the problem lies in the other two. The issue is that you fail to consider the order in which each number is rolled.

Let's start with $\mathbb P\left(A_3\right)$. Of course, the first roll can take on any of the 6 possible values. However, that does not restrict the second roll to 5 different values. If the first two rolls are the same, it's still possible to end up with 3 distinct values after 4 rolls. The same applies to the third roll. So, we should have:
$$\mathbb P\left(A_3\right)=\frac{1}{6^4}\left(6\cdot1\cdot5\cdot4+6\cdot5\cdot2\cdot4+6\cdot5\cdot4\cdot3\right)$$

There's a similar problem for $\mathbb P\left(A_2\right)$, but this one's a little more involved. We can either have 2 pairs of identical rolls or a set of 3 identical rolls and a single unique roll.
$$\mathbb P\left(A_2\right)=\frac 1{6^4}(\overbrace{6\cdot5\cdot2\cdot1+6\cdot1\cdot5\cdot1+6\cdot1\cdot1\cdot5}^\textrm{3 identical rolls}+\overbrace{6\cdot5\cdot2\cdot1+6\cdot1\cdot5\cdot1}^\textrm{2 pairs})$$

These new probabilities line all add up to 1 now, and they line up with the numerical value found with [Python](https://www.online-python.com/1T8Z9YoQEC).